# как сделать QFrame непрозрачным

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

На форму положил `QGroupBox`, на него несколько `QFrame`, на каждом из которых находится несколько кнопок и лейблов. При изменении цвета `QGroupBox`:

```
ui->drBox->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(166,202,240)");
```

всё, что лежит на груп-боксе (кроме текстов) принимает его цвет.
Как сделать фреймы непрозрачными?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Все виджеты-контейнеры имею свойство передавать свои стили дочерним элементам, поэтому нужно, либо указывать селектор точка(.), чтобы модифицировать стиль только самого контейнера, например, `.QWidget`, либо задавать стиль по `objectName`, например, `#lineEdit`.

Answer (score 0):

У QWidget есть метод [setWindowOpacity](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowOpacity-prop), думаю вам надо использовать его и передать ему значение 0.0. К слову QWidget это базовый класс QFrame.